# Complementary pair - Role of capacitor on emitter

Tags: transistors, bjt, darlington, class-a, class-ab

I bought [this](https://quasarelectronics.co.uk/Item/3048-introduction-to-power-audio-amplifiers-kit) little kit for a class AB amplifier.

[image]

The second stage is quite clear (and typical), but I am struggling to understand the role of capacitor C2 on the emitter branch in the first stage. In the explanation they say that this is a *"complementary pair in common emitter mode"*. However, I would expect to see the two emitters connected and either no capacitor or a capacitor as a bypass. This looks an open circuit in DC.

I also built an LTSpice model to check the voltages and it looks like it is being used to keep the base of Q1 at Vcc/2 (approximately).

I have looked around and could not find any other similar example.

Am I reading the circuit incorrectly? Just learning about electronics and amplifiers just for my own education, so please bear with me.

Comment: Regarding C2: 1) **forget** about what the circuit is called 2) ask yourself what happens if 2a) C2 is removed, for DC, C2 is an **open** so not present. 2b) C2 has a very large value so for any AC signal it is a short. 3) Also pay attention to R5 as it connects to the output, hint: feedback.

Comment: To be a "Sziklai pair" the emitter of Q1 would need to connect to the collector of Q2 which it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I am struggling to understand the role of capacitor C2 on the emitter
> branch in the first stage*

If I redrew it like this (where capacitor C2 is removed), does it make more sense: -

[image]

In other words: if you swapped the positions of C2 and R3 in the original circuit, you would see a DC voltage of about 9 volts across C2 (half of the 18 volts DC supply).

Q1 is acting as a differential input device where the base is the input signal and the emitter is where the feedback signal goes. A more sophisticated circuit might use a differential pair amplifier instead but, this will work reasonably well.